# Adding Item to List with Initializer or Add Defined Variable?

Tags: c#, list

i simply wanna ask you is there a difference between initalizer add method and directly veriable add method.

Between This Code Below:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Item() { ID = i, Title = "Item" });
}
```

And This Code:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var item = new Item() { ID = i, Title = "Item" };
    list.Add(item);
}
```

is there a any differences? 
Are they the same code when program is compiled?
if i build a loop from 1 to 1 million am i still gonna get same result (ignore the other effects)?

Comment: `if i build a loop from 1 to 1 million am i still gonna get same result (ignore the other effects)?` -- try it.

Comment: to test that code we should stop all other processes. and there must be only our process. maybe someone knows about it

Comment: To test that code, take what you've put up here and wrap it in a `Stopwatch` to determine the runtime.

Comment: Just an extra line of code thats it...

Comment: @ArgeKumandan, why?  That'll complete in next to no time.

Comment: A good way to check this would be to compile it and look at the resulting IL code. You can use LINQPad for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i compiled the exe and and looked to compiled code on reflector.
Here is my code from PreCompiled Source:

```
        list.Add(new Item() { ID = 2, Title = "Item" });
        Item yeni = new Item() { ID = 4, Title = "Item" };
        list.Add(yeni);
```

And here is the compiled code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
       List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
       Item <>g__initLocal0 = new Item();
       <>g__initLocal0.ID = 2;
       <>g__initLocal0.Title = "Item";
       list.Add(<>g__initLocal0);
       Item <>g__initLocal1 = new Item();
       <>g__initLocal1.ID = 4;
       <>g__initLocal1.Title = "Item";
       Item yeni = <>g__initLocal1;
       list.Add(yeni);
}
```

i just realized compiler takes ur parameter and defines a new veriable than adds it to the list.
Thanx to all you guys.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.  Check out the IL code to see that the `new Item()` has to be stored before it can be added to the list anyways.  However, the first code snippet looks cleaner from a code standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference (the compiler is *smart enough* to produce idential efficient code in both cases *if optimization is on*), but you can make the code a little bit better by setting list *Capasity*:

```
int size = 100000;

var list = new List<Item>(size); // <- setting capacity

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  list.Add(new Item() { ID = i, Title = "Item" });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference, in the second example you are simply storing the newly instantiated item in a variable before adding it to the list whereas in the first example you instantiate and add on the same line. And the variable you store the item in is destructed once you leave the brackets.

Unless you are going to debug what is in the item I would prefer the first set of code, it is nicer to look at.